# prototype function not being invoked

Tags: html, prototypejs

Is there any reason why the below won't work, it seems to work on every scenario except the one below:

My html/asp.net

```
<div class="submitContainerConfirm" id="submit_Div">       
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="phContinue">
        <asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" CssClass="ShowPleaseWait button" runat="server" ID="ibtnContinue" OnClick="ibtnContinue_OnClick" />
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

My prototype

```
function pageLoad() {

$$(".ShowPleaseWait").each(function (el) {
    el.observe("click", function (event) {
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            el.hide();
            el.insert({ after: '<img src="/content/images/processing.gif" /> Please Wait...' });
            alert('Is Valid');
        }
        alert('Is not Valid');
    });
});

}
```

Attempt two:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function () {

Event.observe("click", function (event) {
    if (Page_IsValid) {
        event.hide();
        event.insert({ after: '<img src="/content/images/processing.gif" /> Please Wait...' });
        alert('Is Valid');
    }
    alert('Is not Valid');
});

Event.observe("click", function (event) {
    if (Page_IsValid) {
        event.hide();
        event.insert({ after: '<img src="/content/images/processing.gif" /> Processing...' });
        alert('Is Valid');
    }
    alert('Is not Valid');
});

});
```

// This doesn't work either.
No jquery please.

[Example of asp rendered in html + prototypejs bizarrely not working.](http://jsfiddle.net/VUPKx/3)

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: As in the click functions do not get run/called/invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second attempt, you are not specifying any `element` for the `observe` event to listen on, how will it know which element was clicked?

Try this:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    $$('.ShowPleaseWait').each(function(el) {
        el.observe('click', function(ev) {
            if (Page_IsValid) {
                el.hide();
                el.insert({ 
                    after: '<img src="/content/images/processing.gif" /> Please Wait...'
                });

                alert('Is Valid');
            }

            alert('Is not Valid');
        });
    }); 
});
```

**UPDATE**

see [screenshot of generated page by JSFiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LvM9.jpg), this is the direct output of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VUPKx/5/) fiddle

Comment: thanks for your help, got this up in jsfiddle but doesnt seem the execute still http://jsfiddle.net/VUPKx/3/

Comment: this is because JSFiddle already has an onload event, if you remove it you will see that it actually fires, see update here: http://jsfiddle.net/VUPKx/5/

Comment: @Anicho, does this answer your question?

Comment: Thats half my question, still it refuses to work on an aspx page. Works in html.

Comment: mmh, then you will have to find antoher way to demonstrate the problem to us, as we cannot help if there is no _problem_ shown here :)

Comment: I'll give this you though thanks for your help. I will raise a separate question for asp.net

Comment: :) thanks, just a note about the bounty though, not that I want it or anything, but it never gets awarded back to the owner, so either it gets awarded or it gets lost. from the FAQ: _If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone._

Comment: Yeah I was gonna assign it to you anyway got to wait 24 hours before I can anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't post comments at the moment, with what I see right now though, it doesn't seem Page_IsValid will be triggered as the form has no validation controls. By using @epochs JS solution you can trigger the expected results.

Note: I didn't use any EventHandlers for your OnClick event

See if the following helps by adding a sample textbox to force validation to happen...

```
<div class="submitContainerConfirm" id="submit_Div">       
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="phContinue">
    <asp:TextBox ID="required" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RangeValidator
        ID="rangeValidator"
        ErrorMessage="Enter 0-10"
        runat="server"
        MinimumValue="0"
        MaximumValue="10"
        ControlToValidate="required"></asp:RangeValidator>
    <asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="false" CssClass="ShowPleaseWait button" runat="server" ID="ibtnContinue" OnClick="ibtnContinue_OnClick" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: In epochs jsfiddle example he added var Page_IsValid = true, and in aspnet page I have tested that it gets hit correctly.